# Select one row from multi duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

how to select the first of the highlighted rows, but not the second". So, if the order_num and rest_type is the same only return the first one

I need to select rows without duplicate

note : column headerid it created automatic by DB and very important in select

- the screenshot shows my problem

  SELECT 
      [HeaderId],
      [fkPosCloseId],
      [TransNo],
      [fkRestTransType],
      [Total],
      [TransTypeID],
      [TransDate],
      [InsClosed]
  FROM
      DailyTransHeader
  WHERE
      fkPosCloseId = 230642

Screenshot illustrating my problem:

[image: My Problem]

Comment: Which row do you want to hide? Did you look at GROUP BY?

Comment: I can see the ID is different between two selected rows. So they are not duplicate.

Comment: There are **no duplicates** in your output - every row has at least one column that's different from any othe rrow

Comment: You could simply remove the ID column and SELECT DISTINCT on the other columns..

Comment: I think what the question is asking is "how to select the first of the highlighted rows, but not the second". So, if the rest_type is the same only return the first one.

Comment: Excellent  (  Underverse ) You Read and explain my problem
Thanks For SAS, mkRabbani,marc_s for helping

Comment: need one of repeated rows (headerid it create by db automatic )  but all column is same please check highlighted rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Remove `Header_id` and `InsClosed` since it is not same in both rows.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT    
    [fkPosCloseId],
    [TransNo],
    [fkRestTransType],
    [Total],
    [TransTypeID],
    [TransDate]    
FROM  
    DailyTransHeader       
WHERE
    fkPosCloseId = 230642
    group by 
    [fkPosCloseId],
    [TransNo],
    [fkRestTransType],
    [Total],
    [TransTypeID],
    [TransDate]
```

Or you may try `row_number()`, in that case these fields of `group by` clause is added in `partition by` and `headerid` is taken for `order by`.

```
  Select [Header_id],
    [fkPosCloseId],
    [TransNo],
    [fkRestTransType],
    [Total],
    [TransTypeID],
    [TransDate] 
  from (
  select [Header_id],
    [fkPosCloseId],
    [TransNo],
    [fkRestTransType],
    [Total],
    [TransTypeID],
    [TransDate]   , 
    row_number() over (partition by [fkPosCloseId],[TransNo],[fkRestTransType],
    [Total],[TransTypeID],[TransDate] order by headerId ) as Slno 
    from DailyTransHeader 
    WHERE fkPosCloseId = 230642
    ) as T where t.slno=1
```

This will give the first occurrence of row if everything else is same.

Comment: Thanks For Helping But Code return same rows with duplicated same as ( select * from DailyTransHeader WHERE fkPosCloseId = 230642 ) but  without column (headerid  thats very important for me )

Comment: how to select the first of the highlighted rows, but not the second". So, if the rest_type is the same only return the first one

Comment: Thanks Very Much ***  Second Code Working Fine After editing code2 by this step  1 - add column headerid, after first & second select   2- add WHERE
    fkPosCloseId = 230642  after from DailyTransHeader   And Working Fine Excellent Thanks For Your Helping  ****   first code it return rows only one for duplicated but No column headerid its very important all other sql need  ****

Comment: @norhan: You need to accept answer, there is a tick need to select to accept the ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
SELECT 
    [HeaderId],
    [fkPosCloseId],
    [TransNo],
    [fkRestTransType],
    [Total],
    [TransTypeID],
    [TransDate],
    [InsClosed] ,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by     [HeaderId],
    [fkPosCloseId],
    [TransNo],
    [fkRestTransType],
    [Total],
    [TransTypeID],
    [TransDate]  order by TransTypeID ) rn
FROM  
    DailyTransHeader       
WHERE
    fkPosCloseId = 230642
) t where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks For Helping But Code return same rows with duplicated same as ( select * from DailyTransHeader WHERE fkPosCloseId = 230642 ) but  + column RN Value = 1

Comment: how to select the first of the highlighted rows, but not the second". So, if the rest_type is the same only return the first one